How to Forecast Sales for Sub-Locations Without Historical Proportion Data?
I have a time series dataset of total sales for a product in a store over time. This product is available in two different locations within the store: one stand near the checkout and another stand in the center of the store.
Currently, I only have the total sales data for the product across the whole store. I need to forecast sales separately for each stand. This seems like a hierarchical forecasting problem using a top-down approach, where the total sales are disaggregated into the sub-locations.
However, I don't have historical data for each stand, so I don't know the proportions of sales attributable to each location.
What methods or approaches can I use to estimate these proportions and make accurate forecasts for each stand?

Would you even be able to record whether a given sale came from one or the other location? Thus, would you even be able to assess the quality of your forecasts?

@StephanKolassa There is no way to record where the item that was sold came from. The data we have is the total sale of the product in the store. The way to evaluate accuracy would be with the total sale

So just forecast total sales and distribute them equally between the two stands. If whoever is asking for the disaggregate forecast does not like that, then let them propose any other distribution. Or draw a random weight from [0,1] for each separate forecast. Given the information you have, there is no reason to prefer one distribution over another one. Walk your client/manager/whoever through exactly why they would not like this. There simply is no way around getting disaggregate information if you want meaningful disaggregate forecasts.
